# Updating value from another table only if different

Tags: sql, sql-update, union

I have 2 tables, A and B, both have ID and Value. (Using SQL Server)

A:

```
         ID VALUE
=========== ==========
          1 A
          2 A
          2 D
```

B:

```
         ID VALUE
=========== ==========
          1 C
          2 D
```

After the update, I want A to look like:

A:

```
         ID VALUE
=========== ==========
          1 C
          2 D
          2 D
```

I want the query to only update when the values are not equals. For example, 2 would get updated to D but only once. Affecting 2 rows in total.

Currently my query is:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Value= A.Value
FROM B
WHERE A.ID= B.ID
```

Is there anyway to only updates when the Value are not equals ?

The reason I want to only updates rows that are not equals is to keep track of what is modified.

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your question seems ambiguous as the number of values increases in each table.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the post to say im using Sql Server. And the value does increase in each tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this should work for you

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Value = B.Value
FROM B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND A.Value <> B.Value
```

Example https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/380722#resultSets

Comment: Thank you for that, made me realized that my second table wasn't the way it should be.